# show phone case in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

I'm using xCode7.3 and I need to stay with it. I cannot expand it with mouse dragging.

How can I got phone case like [image: this]

Now I got something like [image: this]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get any kind of "phone case" in the simulator with Xcode 7 or 8. The simulator in Xcode 9 now shows the bezel but it's still not photo realistic like your 1st photo.

To get something like your first photo you need to combine a screenshot with the official product images from Apple found at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images